# FontAwesome thickness as icon vs CSS content psuedo selector

Tags: html, css, font-awesome, pseudo-element

I'm noticing the thickness of FontAwesome icons render thicker when adding them as content to a CSS pseudo selector vs the actual icon tag.  I can't figure out what is causes this.  Seeing it in Chrome and Safari...

**Thinner**

```
<i class="fa fa-toggle-on"></i>
```

**vs. Thicker**

```
span:after { 
    font-family:'FontAwesome';
    content:'\f205';
}
```

Comment: Have you checked the `font-width` the `i` and `span` elements get from elsewhere in the stylesheet? Can you show a live example?

Comment: They are the same from a clean page: http://jsfiddle.net/2eme0c12/ there must be some other CSS in your app that is changing it.

Comment: After checking out the FontAwesome stylesheet... It seems added 
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
solves the problem